# Text is too closely spaced preceding empheq environment

Tags: formatting, document-classes, line-spacing, thesis, empheq

This is a follow-up question regarding a previous question:

[Previous Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246071/empheqlbrace-autoscaling-problem-with-dukedissertation-document-class)

In the dukedissertation document class the solution given in the link provided above leads to improper line spacing preceding any use of the empheq environment.

How can I retain the left-bracket fix provided as an answer to my previous question without it causing improper line spacing in the paragraph preceding an empheq environment?

The following is a minimal working example illustrating the line-spacing problem.

```
\documentclass[]{dukedissertation}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\AtBeginEnvironment{empheq}{\linespread{1.3}\selectfont\normalbaselines}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter Something}

A new chapter.

\section{Section Something}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu mollis
tortor. Sed massa quam, pellentesque quis metus id, ultrices scelerisque
libero. Donec in magna sapien. Donec sit amet odio sed lectus sodales
accumsan. Etiam rutrum ultricies congue. Fusce laoreet nulla in massa
rhoncus, a cursus ligula aliquam.
\textbf{Text preceding the empheq environment is too closely spaced.}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{empheq}[left=(1.1)\empheqlbrace]{align}
    v &= \dot{x}\\
    a &= \dot{v}\\
    j &= \dot{a}
\end{empheq}
\end{subequations}
\textbf{Text afterwards is just fine.}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu mollis
tortor. Sed massa quam, pellentesque quis metus id, ultrices scelerisque
libero. Donec in magna sapien. Donec sit amet odio sed lectus sodales
accumsan. Etiam rutrum ultricies congue. Fusce laoreet nulla in massa
rhoncus, a cursus ligula aliquam.

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: On you image, it seems to be the same spacing above and below the environment.

Comment: @Bernard The OP is referring to \baselineskip in the paragraphs before and after the environment.

Comment: I have fixed the answer to the linked question

Comment: @egreg Thank you: the modification you made to your answer to my previous question solves the problem.  I'm posting via comment as I don't know how to credit you with solving the problem otherwise.

Comment: @BenderOrszagIsGoodStuff I guess this question might be removed.